# How can I pass parameters in a [Setup] or [OneTimeSetup] so I so not have call the method in my test class?

Tags: c#, nunit, extentreports

In TestNg We have @BeforeMethod where we can pass parameters. 
But in Nunit I get this exception  "OneTimeSetUp: SetUp and TearDown methods must not have parameters: TestInitialize" I am trying to Create the extent report for each test in the class with out calling .CreateTest method in every [Test] method

```
[SetUp]
 public void TestInitialize(MethodInfo method)
 {
    StartReport(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
    string testName = method.Name;
    test = extent.CreateTest(testName);
 }

 [Test]
  public void GetHealthTest()
  {
            test.Log(Status.Info, "Before calling GetHealth API");
            var health = heartbeat.GetHealth();
            test.Log(Status.Info, "After GetHealth API call");
            Assert.AreEqual(health.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.OK);

  }
```

Comment: It says, you can't use param for the [Setup]. What do you want to do?

Comment: @Alex-TinLe I am trying to create the test report with out mentioning .createTest in every method. I want to mention it once so it applies to every [Test] method

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the name of the current test in your `SetUp`, use `TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name`. There are other properties, like `FullName` and `MethodName` as well, depending on what you prefer to see in your report.

That said, even with use of `SetUp`, this is a very "busy" way to do reporting. NUnit also supports engine extensions, which allow you to create reports outside of the test assembly itself. In addition, it's possible to simply write a program that reads the XML result file from a test run and creates a report.

Comment: is their any documentation on this. This is similar to like a TestNG.xml file. All I need is some outputs like Total pass, failed, skipped report

Comment: Yes. It's in the NUnit docs... https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NUnit-Documentation